# Make the second combo-box item selected based on item selection of first combo box

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to update the combo box **cbo_moduleName** based on the selection made in **cbo_moduleCode**. Right now the user has to select the combo box to make their selection but I want the first value found during the loop to be automatically filled "on the fly". Any idea on how I can achieve this? Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub cbo_moduleCode_Change()

    Dim lLoop As Long
    ' Clear the comboboxes we are about to update
    Me.cbo_moduleName.Clear

    ' Loop through the worksheet and test each row
    For lLoop = 1 To Sheets("lookupModule").Range("A" & Sheets("lookupModule").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ' If the row's column A matches the combobox then add the corresponding values to other combos
        If Sheets("lookupModule").Range("A" & lLoop).Value = Me.cbo_moduleCode.Value Then
            Me.cbo_moduleName.AddItem Sheets("lookupModule").Range("B" & lLoop).Value
        End If
    Next lLoop

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "on the fly"?

Comment: `cbo_moduleName` value remains empty until the user selects the drop down to see the options. I want the `cbo_moduleName` to be updated in real time with the users selection in `cbo_moduleCode`.

Comment: Isn't that what your code doing? i.e. when the selection in cbo_moduleCode changes, doesn't the event `cbo_moduleCode_Change()` fire?

Comment: Yes but the update is not simultaneous, the cbo_moduleName remains blank until the user clicks the drop down button

Comment: What should be the contents of `cbo_moduleName` till the user makes any selection in cbo_moduleCode`?

Comment: It should be clear. As soon as the user makes a selection in `cbo_moduleCode` then it should automatically update `cbo_moduleName` with the current value but unfortunately it doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18369/discussion-between-shahkalpesh-and-methuselah)

Comment: The answer based on the chat discussion is added below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the 1st item of `cbo_moduleName` selected when the user selection of `cbo_moduleCode` changes, here is the code

```
If Me.cbo_moduleName.ListCount > 0 Then
   Me.cbo_moduleName.ListIndex = -1
End If
```